# Piccasso Error on Image Adapter Class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-adapter, picasso

I have created an upload image section using Firebase for my application. But when I tried to load the Image using **Recycler view** and **ImageAdapter** its crashing. I am thinking Error on loading Picasso.

My Adapter Class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;



public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}

@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());

    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
            .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                    //Here your log
                }
            })
            .build();
    picasso.load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
    }
}
```

The following section is in my main Gallery Activity

```
 mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

            mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(Gallery.this, mUploads);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Gallery.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Where I did wrong?Please help me in coding error.

Comment: crashing log ?.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
            .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                    //Here your log
                }
            })
            .build();
    picasso.load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
```

you should first load the resource before adding a listener to it

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
            .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
            .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                    //Here your log
                }
            })
            .build();
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
```

also you can use a listener inyour .into

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                .build();
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView,, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Error:-Builder (Context) in Builder cannot be applied to ImageAdapter

Comment: Error in Context on this

`Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this){/*}`

Answer (score 0):

Picasso changes some parameters that caused error

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
    Picasso.get()
            .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
}
```

they changed

```
Picasso.with(Context)
```

to

```
Picasso.get()
```

Thanks for the support... This may help the people staked like me....

Comment: Glad you fixed it buddy

Comment: Thanks buddy. Keep support me